# Join and fetch columns based on priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    product CHAR(3), 
    yr CHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('a', '2019');
INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('m', '2019');

CREATE TABLE customers
(
    cus_name CHAR(20), 
    columnX CHAR(3), 
    columnY CHAR(3),
    price INT
);

INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('john', 'b', 'a', 100);
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('brad', 'a', 'd', 200);
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('chris', 'm', 'y', 200);
INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('Luis', 'r', 'm', 200);
```

I want to join orders table with customers table based on the column `product` in the `orders` table.

I want to fetch one `price` based on columns `columnY` or `columnX` for every product.

`columnY` should be given first priority. If product exists in `columnY` then fetch price from that row.

If it doesn't exist, then check `columnX` and fetch that price.

The below query with OR operation gives me both rows but I only want only the first row with `cus_name` as John

```
select *
from orders a
left join customers c on a.product = c.columnY 
                      or a.product = c.columnX
```

| product | yr | cus_name | columnX | columnY | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2019 | john | b | a | 100 |
| a | 2019 | brad | a | d | 200 |
| m | 2019 | chris | m | y | 200 |
| m | 2019 | Luis | r | m | 200 |

---

Expected output would be:

| product | yr | cus_name | columnX | columnY | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2019 | john | b | a | 100 |
| m | 2019 | luis | r | m | 200 |

Thanks in advance

Edit for clarity: every product will occur only once in `columnX` and `columnY`, i.e. `ColumnY` and `ColumnX` cannot have more than one Product 'a'

Edit 2 - Included multiple products in the orders table.

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting John over Brad? Maybe a simple `TOP 1`?

Comment: Yes, in the above example criteria would be whenever the product 'a' appears first in the columnY of customers table

Comment: What if 2 rows existed with the product in Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you can order by your defined priority and then use [`TOP` 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to take to first row.

This doesn't solve the issue of having 2 rows matching your priority though.

```
select top 1 *
from orders a
left join customers c on 
    a.product = c.columnY 
    or a.product = c.columnX
order by case when a.product = c.columnY then 1 else 0 end desc;
```

With your clarification which require multiple products you need a completely different solution. A common solution is to using the [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window function to find the first row per product e.g.

```
with cte as (
    select *
        -- Use the same ordering as before, but now partitioned by product.
        , row_number() over (partition by a.product order by case when a.product = c.columnY then 1 else 0 end desc) rn
    from #orders a
    left join #customers c on 
        a.product = c.columnY 
        or a.product = c.columnX
)
select product, yr, cus_name, columnX, columnY, price
from cte
-- Only pick the first result, ordered by our priority, per product
where rn = 1
order by product, yr, cus_name;
```

Which returns:

| product | yr | cus_name | columnX | columnY | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2019 | john | b | a | 100 |
| m | 2019 | Luis | r | m | 200 |

Comment: I'd have to modify this code to get top 1 for each product. Group by product and get Top 1 for each product. Thank you so much

Comment: sorry about that and thanks for letting me know. I just re updated it. Hopefully i will get better at asking questions in stack overflow

Comment: perfect. This works

Answer (score 0):

I changed @Dale answer based on comments and prepare the example (don't know is this helpful that if there is muliple year entries)

```
Declare @orders TABLE(product CHAR(3), yr CHAR(4));
INSERT INTO @orders VALUES ('a', '2019');
INSERT INTO @orders VALUES ('a', '2020');

Declare @customers TABLE(cus_name CHAR(20), columnX CHAR(3), columnY CHAR(3),price int );
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES ('john', 'b','a',100);
INSERT INTO @customers VALUES ('brad', 'a','d',200);

Select *
from @orders a
left join @customers c on 
    case when a.product = c.columnY then a.product else c.columnY end = a.product
    --a.product = c.columnY 
 --   or a.product = c.columnX
order by case when a.product = c.columnY then 1 else 0 end desc;
```

**Result**

[image]

if we remove the 2020 entry(same as current situation, then result will be)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would find all the target values for column "ColumnY" via "Intersect" and then use them as a filter.

```
Select orders.product, orders.yr, customers.cus_name, customers.columnX, customers.columnY, customers.price
From customers Inner Join orders On (customers.columnY=orders.product)
Where columnY In (Select columnY From customers 
                  Intersect
                  Select columnX From customers)
```